# Create and write to a .pages file using Terminal

Tags: terminal, pages

Is it possible to create and write on a `.pages` document file via Terminal.app?

I have tried it as explained below but it didn't work. As I understand, I was able to create a `.pages` file but the binary format wasn't correct.

```
 touch file.pages  #CREATE THE FILE
 open -a Pages file.pages #OPEN THE FILE WITH PAGES (Pages can not open file.pages)
```

I have had the same result with following:

```
ls -l >> file.pages
open -a Pages file.page
```

I have also tried using different extensions:**no extension**, **txt**, **rtf**, **doc**, but Pages.app cannot open the file.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

- A Pages document is not a simple file, but a **Zip archive**.
- A Pages document contains much **more than just plain text**. A blank document is still based on a template, with a set page size and other metadata.

Creating a blank document in Pages creates this structure:

[image]

To create a Pages document programatically, use AppleScript to tell Pages to do it for you.

```
tell application "Pages" to ¬
  save (make new document) in file "Macintosh HD:path:to:folder:Blank.pages"
```

To run AppleScript from the command line, use osascript.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Pages" to save (make new document) in file "Macintosh HD:path:to:folder:Blank.pages"'
```

Comment: Technically a ZIP archive *is* a file :-)

Comment: @nohillside A very good point! I was intending to write "package" instead of Zip which would definitely not be a file, but then found out [Pages changed the default back to single file recently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2oVn.png). Thanks for the edit

Comment: I don't want save the document into an existing file. I want to create a new file, and I cannot do this with this applescript. @grg

Comment: @federico `save (make new document)` makes a new document and immediately saves that new document, creating it on disk. There is no existing file for the AppleScript above, you provide a path for the new document to be saved at.